# Is it possible to write and send a file with Discord.py without saving to hard drive?

Tags: python, csv, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that compiles information from channel messages and converts it into a CSV file that it can then send back to the user. Currently, I'm writing the file to my hard drive and then sending that file (working code below).

```
csv = open('pyro.csv', 'w')
csv.write('date,store,sku,size,product,profile,proxies,order\n')

# PULL DATA FROM CHANNEL
try:
   for m in history:
      if m.webhook_id == ECB_ID and date_1 <= m.created_at.date() <= date_2:
         for e in m.embeds:
            fields = e.to_dict().get('fields')
            if fields is not None and len(fields) == 7:
               product = fields[3].get('value')

               if target_product in product.lower():
                  store = fields[0].get('value')
                  sku = fields[1].get('value')
                  size = fields[2].get('value')
                  profile = fields[4].get('value').split('||')[1]
                  proxies = fields[5].get('value').split('||')[1]
                  order = fields[6].get('value').split('||')[1]
                  csv.write(m.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%y') + "," + store + "," + sku + "," + size + "," + product + "," + profile + "," + proxies + "," + order + "\n")
except:
   await ch.send('Error: data error')
   return

# SEND CSV MESSAGE
try:
   csv.close()
   await ch.send("CSV", file=discord.File('pyro.csv'))
```

But I would love to be able to do the same thing without having to store a file to my hard drive before sending it. Is there any way I can accomplish that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a `BytesIO` file-like object:

```
import io

buf = io.BytesIO(b'thedata')
f = discord.File(buf, filename='filename_shown_in_discord.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import io
import csv
import discord

header = ['Some', 'Header']
data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

buffer = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buffer)
writer.writerow(header)
writer.writerows(data)
buffer.seek(0) #Don't know why this is here, but it worked...

await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(buffer, 'some-file.csv'))
```